# Потоковая передача видео на сервер

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Прошарил весь гугл, но так и не понял даже в какую сторону идти...

Как можно реализовать стриминг изображения с телефона (с его рабочего стола) на сервер, а потом с другого телефона это изображение просмотреть (более-менее в реальном времени)?

Comment: rtcp думаю поможет

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо смотреть в сторону [UPnP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP) или [DLNA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLNA)

То есть одно устройство должно выступать UPnP/DLNA сервером, а второе соответственно UPnP/DLNA клиентом.

Библиотек реализующих оба этих протокола много, ну [например](https://github.com/4thline/cling)

Comment: Сеть же вроде домашней должна быть по dlna